# fragment transaction error in android not applicable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop

Hello I switched my theme to "@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar".. API 21.

Everything works apart from when I add or replace fragments.

```
transaction.add(R.id.frame, new OneFragment());
```

In eclipse the error says.. "The method add(int, fragment) in the type fragment transaction is not applicable for the arguments (int,OneFragment)"

This was working before I tried changing the theme.
 My app runs perfectly with the new theme but I get error in the fragment section as mentioned above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> "The method add(int, fragment) in the type fragment transaction is
>   not applicable for the arguments (int,OneFragment)"

it is usually due to some inconsistency between the `Fragment`'s imports. For instance it happens when you use the native `FragmentManager` and the imports of your `Fragment`'s subclass are from the support library (or the other way around)